# How to mount remote path inside docker cotainer using kubernetes & sshfs?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh, openssh, sshfs

I am trying to mount remote path inside docker container image using sshfs, which will going to run on kubernetes cluster.

**Problem**
The issue is there is not error & after run the server nginx does not respond. If I comment the `CMD` part its working.

Nginx Pod Status is `CrashLoopBackOff` but when not running the sshfs, its working

**Dockerfile-nginx**

```
FROM nginx:1.20.2-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add sshfs

COPY nginx/key.pem /home/files

RUN echo "user_allow_other" | tee -a /etc/fuse.conf
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/shared
RUN chmod 600 /home/files/key.pem

CMD sh -c "sshfs root@x.x.x.x:/home /mnt/shared -o debug -o allow_other -o idmap=user,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) -o ssh_command='ssh -i /home/files/key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"
```

**Kubernetes Pod**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: kube_nginx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `ssh-server` is already installed on remote system. `sshfs` is the client which I already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

If anyone facing this issue here is the entire code

**Dockerfile-nginx**

```
FROM nginx:1.20.2-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add sshfs

COPY nginx/key.pem /home/files

RUN mkdir -p /mnt/shared
RUN chmod 600 /home/files/key.pem

CMD sh -c "sshfs root@x.x.x.x:/home /mnt/shared -o IdentityFile=/home/files/key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

**Kubernetes Pod**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: kube_nginx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```